# Should a Record Center in SP2013 have its own Web App?

Tags: records-center

We are looking at provisioning our first Record Center. What is the best topology?

Should it be in its own web app or can I provision a new Site Collection in its own Content database?

Answer (score 0):

Own Web app is not good Idea, But I would go with creating a new site with Record center and (if i will huge amount of data) then i would with Own Content Database.